# Ember.Select not selecting first entry after populating data

Tags: ember.js

I have a `Ember.Select` that starts out empty.  Once it has been populated the first item is automatically displayed in the dropdown but it does not always select (binding-wide).  It seems to depend upon where the populating happens:

If done in the `setupController` function of the route then it selects.

For `actions` it does not.

The only work-around that I have found is to set the selected item yourself after the population has completed.

Am I missing something or is the 'work-around' the way to actually handle this when it is not set implicitly?

I have put together a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbenRoux/ReWqR/)

Comment: Thanks for your post and the jsFiddle. I just want to add that I've run into this same issue and not found a better workaround.  Would love to hear if there is one.